# How to show the value of a javascript variable in a label tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working in a JavaScript file, and have come across something that is stumping me.

In the .js file I am adding something to a unordered list. I am doing this like so...

`$("#listID").append("<label>stuff</label>");`

The kicker is I would like the "stuff" in the label to be mixed static text, and the value of a JavaScript variable.

In the end it would display something like "I like ___ cars" where the blank will be the value of some variable $color.

I have already tried something like `<label>${$color}</label>` but that just outputs `"${$color}"` I want it to output `red` if red is the value of $color.

Thanks for the read. Anything will be appreciated.

Comment: .append("<label>"+stuffvariable+"</label>");

Comment: use simple string / variable concatenation

Comment: I must have totally had a brain fart. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the label, set its contents based on an expression (not just a string), then append to `#listID`:

```
var color = "red";

$('<label>').
  text("I like " + color + " cars.").
  appendTo( "#listID" );
```

Comment: Thanks this works too. I forgot about the concatenation as well.